# How to resolve error AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm a beginner in python and web scraping.
I'm trying to scrape information from a quiz site, using python along with `beautifulsoup`.

I can scrape the questions and answers individually.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'https://rachacuca.com.br/quiz/18992/bleach-sagas/'

r = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')


perguntas = soup.find('ol').li.p.text
#print(perguntas)
respostas = soup.find('ol').find('div', class_='alternativa-texto').p.text
#print(respostas)

todos_elementos = soup.find_all('ol')
#print(todos_elementos)

for elemento in todos_elementos:
  perguntas = elemento.find('ol').find('li').p.text
  respostas = elemento.find('div', class_='alternativa-texto').p.text

  print(f'perguntas: {perguntas}')
  print(f'respostas: {respostas}')
  print('-'*70)
```

But when I gather all the elements to print, I get this error:

```
 AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-45-a6fe913d7109> in <module>()
      1 for elemento in todos_elementos:
----> 2   perguntas = elemento.find('ol').find('li').p.text
      3   respostas = elemento.find('div', class_='alternativa-texto').p.text
      4 
      5   print(f'perguntas: {perguntas}')

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'
```

Comment: Well, the first step is to analyze what has happened. Is `elemento` None? How about `elemento.find('ol')`? How was `todos_elementos` calculated, and therefore what kind of tag do you expect `elemento` to represent?

Comment: Karl Knechtel, sorry for my ignorance, but what should i analyze in element.find ('ol')?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the iterating through the answers didn't go well because there is a mix of radio buttons and input boxes. Make sure you handle the exceptions when the answer structure is different. Try the following:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'https://rachacuca.com.br/quiz/18992/bleach-sagas/'

r = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')

# Find the top elements
elems = soup.find('ol').find_all('li', recursive=False)
questions = []
for elem in elems:
    # Question
    print(elem.find('p').text)
    question = {'text': elem.find('p').text}
    # Answer
    try:
        print(elem.find('div', class_='alternativa-texto').p.text)
        question['answer'] = elem.find('div', class_='alternativa-texto').p.text
    except:
        print("Error: element has no paragraph. Maybe an input box?")
    questions.append(question)

print(questions)
```

Comment: Worked perfectly.
Thank you!

If I also want to get all the answers in the printout, how should I proceed?

Comment: See the updated answer. Simply store the questions in a list, and make every question/answer a dictionary to add to that list.

Comment: Can you give an example as you do, or indicate a content where I can obtain this knowledge?
please.

Comment: Please take another look at my answer and notice the `questions` list and `question` dictionary.

Comment: The first version you posted was more functional. I liked her better.
I want to export it in csv.
How would be the command to generate a csv.

Comment: Either you use a step in between and use the `pandas` module to convert the `questions` list to a table/dataframe and then use `dataframe.to_csv` to write the results to a CSV file. Otherwise take a look at the `csv` module and use the CSV writer `writerow` to write to a file.